# Variable length error in loop in r

Tags: r, variables, anova

I am trying to loop in r to get multiple Anova results. However I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = col ~ Total, data = phil_data, 
:variable lengths differ (found for 'Total')
```

I don't understand where this comes from as the Anova works outside the loop (see code). Any help is much appreciated.

```
multi.hist(phil_data[,c(7:23)],density=TRUE,freq=TRUE,bcol="cyan",main=" ")
anovaresult <- anova(aov(x2 ~ Total, data=phil_data))
print(anovaresult)
anovaresult <- anova(aov(x1 ~ Total, data=phil_data))
print(anovaresult)

for(i in c(3, 7:23)){
    col <- colnames(phil_data)[i]
    print(col)
    anovaresult <- anova(aov(col~Total,data=phil_data))
    print(anovaresult)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    multi.hist(phil_data[,c(7:23)],density=TRUE,freq=TRUE,bcol="cyan",main=" ")
anovaresult <- anova(aov(x2 ~ Total, data=phil_data))
print(anovaresult)
anovaresult <- anova(aov(x1 ~ Total, data=phil_data))
print(anovaresult)

for(i in c(3, 7:23)){
    col[i] <- colnames(phil_data)[i]## add the i index
    print(col[i])
    anovaresult <- anova(aov(phil_data[,col[i]]~Total,data=phil_data))
    print(anovaresult)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however it just changed the error to:
    Error in model.frame.default(formula = phil_data[, col[i]] ~ Total, data = 
    phil_data,  : 
      invalid type (list) for variable 'phil_data[, col[i]]'

Comment: i don't know the type of your dataset but for me this work well :
for(i in c(1:5)){
    col[i] <- colnames(mtcars)[i]
    print(col[i])
    anovaresult <- anova(aov(mtcars[,col[i]]~disp,data=mtcars))
    print(anovaresult)
}
[1] "mpg"
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: mtcars[, col[i]]
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
disp       1 808.89  808.89  76.513 9.38e-10 ***
Residuals 30 317.16   10.57                     
---